# how to support polars in pycaret?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-polars, pycaret

I have a question that seems simple, but after I start thinking about it, it seems to be a little complicated...

The well-known Pycaret package only uses Pandas... but with the growing popularity of Polars, I'm starting to think about opening a pull-request to support Polars... the question is how this should be done....

there are many pd.DataFrame(...) lines, and I can't use an if condition to check the dataset type to know whether I should use pd.DataFrame(...) or pl.DataFrame(...)

Does anyone know how to do it? Any ideas?

Comment: In this case, I'd suggest opening a feature request with the repo, mentioning that you'd be willing to work on this. I am sure someone from the team can point you to the right directions.